# JBoss EAP 7 => ClassCastException: org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference cannot be cast to org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x, pom.xml

I am getting this error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference cannot be cast to org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference

Maybe the problem is on the jboss-deployment-structure.xml of the servlet:

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
  <deployment>
    <dependencies>
      <module name="javax.api"/>
      <module name="org.apache.santuario.xmlsec"/>
      <module name="org.apache.xerces" />
      <system export="true">
        <paths> 
          <path name="com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/dom"/>
        </paths>
      </system>
    </dependencies>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Do you have any hint of whats going on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have 2 different version of xmlsec,jar (i think 1.4.x and 1.5.x)

Comment: how can I choose a specific version?

Comment: First goes with Jboss - check `$JBOSS_HOME/modules/org/apache/santuario/xmlsec/main` in my setup it  xmlsec-1.5.1.jar, and second goes as dependency in pom.xml, maybe indirect. run `mvn dependency:tree` and i bet you find xmlsec-1.4.x.jar

Comment: Ok, i think you are right because i got it solved by commenting  <module name="org.apache.santuario.xmlsec"/> in the jboss-deployment-structure.xml .Could you anser this question explaining whats going on (i dont understand at 100% what ´s happening)  How can the servlet import 2 different versions of the samy library?When you answer I will mark it as answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is different xmlsec library version. 
`org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference` located in xmlsec-1.5.1.jar (org.apache.santuario.xmlsec module in JBoss)
`org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference` located in xmlsec-1.4.3.jar (dependency in your pom.xml)

Jboss 7 uses isolated modules https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7 it is complicated and i really don't know how it works inside.

But if simplify, when jboss start, it loads xmlsec-1.5.1, when start your application, it loads xmlsec-1.4.3. As result you have class cast exception, when pass DOMReference object between jboss and webapp classloders.

You can resolve your issue in different ways:

- remove dependency of `org.apache.santuario.xmlsec` module in jboss-deployment-structure.xml. Application will use his own defined xmlsec-1.4.3 library
- locate dependency `xmlsec` in pom.xml, set version to 1.5.1, and set scope to `provided`. Application will use JBoss module with xmlsec-1.5.1
- locate dependency `xmlsec` in pom.xml and exclude it completly, if your code complies without `xmlsec` dependency. Application will use JBoss module with xmlsec-1.5.1

`mvn:dependency:tree` command helps here.